# Worksheet_SelectionChange not firing from Selection.Offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to use the selection of a cell in a given column as an event.  This works if I physically mouse click or arrow into a cell in the column.

I would like to though, get to this column by using Selection.Offset or ActiveCell.Offset or something similar.  But when a cell in the given column is selected via this offset function, it doesn't seem to count as a SelectionChange event and therefore doesn't activate my next macro.

1. When Data is entered into "Height" column, Call Height_To_Comments()
2. Height_To_Comments() moves over to "Comments" from "Height" in same row
3. With or without data entry, in "Comments" Column, ENTER calls Comments_To_Weight()
4. Comments_To_Weight() moves back to "Weight" from "Comments" and down a row

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H3:H52")) Is Nothing Then
   Call Height_To_Comments
   End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   x = 0
   For Each cell In Target
   If cell.Column <> 13 Then x = 1
   Application.OnKey "~"
   Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"
   Next cell
   If x = 0 Then
   Application.OnKey "~", "Comments_To_Weight"
   Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "Comments_To_Weight"
       End If
   End Sub


   Sub Height_To_Comments()
   Selection.Offset(-1, 5).Select
   End Sub

   Sub Comments_To_Weight()
   Selection.Offset(1, -7).Select
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: As an aside, in your `If` statement, do you want the `OnKey` events to occur only if the column is not 13?

Comment: `If cell.Column = 13 Then x = 1` and then swapping the `OnKey` events also works.  I can't remember why I did it sort of backwards, but I played with it a lot when troubleshooting.

Comment: I asked because the way it's written is the two `OnKey` events will *always* occur, no matter what the `cell.column` is. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I had changed the function of "~" and "{ENTER}" only after there had been a selection change in the comments column itself (rather than on the prior height column before the curser arrives in the comments column).  I changed it so that when a selection change was made in the height column, THEN the function of "~" and "{ENTER}" changes.  So once the data is entered into height, the sheet tabs over to comments, then when the user hits ENTER or ~ it correctly goes back to weight on the next line, rather than enter just going to the next line and then the next time enter is hit it goes to the next row and left 7 columns.

Changed `If cell.Column <> 13 Then x = 1` to `If cell.Column <> 8 Then x = 1`.